# using webshims and modernizr for older browser support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, modernizr

I am working on a JQM mobile website, and i am requaired to add support for IE8 and under using modernizr, in my project i use features like geolocation, canvas, localStorage, html5 forms and css3 design, i am trying to use webshims, which, to my understanding, support all this features but i must have missed somthing when reading the documentation because i dont think its working very well (tried the IE developer tools emulator to test it but nothing happned), here is the top of my html code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html clas="no-js">
<head>
      <title>Ziv's car rental</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

```
   <script src="scripts/modernizr.custom.75297.js"></script>   
<script src="scripts/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $.webshims.polyfill()
});

</script>
```

the "polyfiller.js" is the js file that came with the webshims, 
what am i missing?

Comment: jQuery Mobile + IE8... Huh?

Comment: yea it sounded weird when i was told i have to have support for that... ifigure that out later though, anyway, i still cant get the modernizr to work, even on the IE11, so basicaly my question still stands at, how to do i get modrnizer to do anything, other then adding the classes it doesnt do anything

Comment: Yes, webshims adds support for all of this. The polyfiller.js depends an modernizr + jQuery. Is jQuery included above polyfiller? Additionaly polyfiller is only the base file and will load other features from the shims folder. Have you added this folder to your project. What is the console saying in IE8-11 or Firefox?

Comment: i didnt include all the lines in this sample code but yes i have jquery and jqm all in my scrpit tags, the console, is stopinf the action ,saying, for example, that localStorage is null, which led me to understand it does not create any replacment for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modernizr doesn't necessarily do anything besides feature detection. For example, if you wanted to do a check in javascript for, lets say css transition support, you would do something like this:

```
if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
  // Do modern things
} else {
  // Do old things
}
```

As for the classes it adds to the HTML element, that is up to you how to use them via stylesheets.

Comment: so basically all i can do with modernizer is pop some alert or something that says that feature is not supported? what about the webshims? shouldnt they take affect if i use '$.webshims.polyfill()'?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of a polyfill you are trying to use via the Webshims library?

Comment: i tried using the $.webshims.polyfill() which should include all of them and also tried $.webshims.polyfill('forms'); and others, nothing seems to do anything

Comment: Take a look at [this page](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/shiv.html) and make sure your initialization and structure are proper.